# What's the metal clinking sound at the end of credits in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, credits, avengers-endgame

*Avengers: Endgame*, unlike other movies in the MCU, doesn't have a post credit scene.

During my first watch, I heard a distinct metal clinking sound at the end of the credits. I thought it was coming from outside the theater as the exit doors were already open. But, on my second watch, I heard the same sound at the same moment.

What's that sound and what's its significance?

Comment: I realize the official answer is that it is Tony building his first suit but I like to think it's Morgan in garage building a new one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Paulie_D answered it pretty well but here are the official wordings:

From [bgr](https://bgr.com/2019/04/30/nintendo-switch-secret-feature-boost-mode-update-8-0-0/) Russos said:

> Q: There were some metal smashing sound when the movie ended. Was that an easter egg? or just a tribute to Iron Man, or maybe an implication that Iron Man will return?
>
> A: It was our way to say goodbye to him.

Also from [usatoday](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2019/04/30/why-avengers-endgame-doesnt-have-end-credits-scene-spoilers/3630412002/):

> There is a little something extra, though, as the final "Endgame" credits roll and that familiar Marvel Studios logo pops up onscreen: In the background, you can hear the clanging of Stark (Robert Downey Jr.) building his first Iron Man armor in the original movie.
>
> Anthony Russo calls it "an echo of the past" rather than a tease to someone else wearing the iconic supersuit at a later date.
>
> "It's really just an homage, sort of a little bookend," Joe Russo says. "It started it and it ends it."

Answer (score 45):

From this question & answer at Science Fiction & Fantasy

[**What’s with the clanks at the end of the credits in Avengers: Endgame?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/210743/what-s-with-the-clanks-at-the-end-of-the-credits-in-avengers-endgame)

> According to [Vanity Fair](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2019/04/avengers-endgame-end-of-credits-sound-iron-man-armor-hammer-suit) Disney have confirmed....
>
> > There is no traditional Marvel end-of-credits scene or teaser in Avengers: Endgame—but there is a little treat for patient fans who sat through the movie’s very, very, very, long credits sequence. Listen closely, and you’ll hear some clanging. Does it sound familiar? **Disney has confirmed that the sound you hear is Tony Stark building his first makeshift Iron Man suit, in the M.C.U. movie that started it all**.

Comment: [This USA Today article might be helpful too](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2019/04/30/why-avengers-endgame-doesnt-have-end-credits-scene-spoilers/3630412002/). Especially considering that, the Vanity Fair one is unsourced I believe.