# Is there an official reason for not adding a post-credits scene?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In most of the MCU films, we get to see credit scenes (from around 1 to 3). But in *Avengers: Endgame* there was no mid/end credit scene, just a [clinking sound](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/100112/1190). So did they ever said anything officially to address why they avoided an end credits​ scene? I mean it's not the end of MCU and at-least *Spider-Man: Far From Home* is coming soon.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yeah, it was "never in the cards", *Endgame* being, well, an ending, etc. From an interview with *USA Today*:

> But the newest blockbuster "Avengers: Endgame" – an action-packed, emotionally exhausting three-hour culmination of the 22-film saga so far – breaks from tradition by skipping Marvel's usual stingers, which have at times teased to the next movie in the series or just been a quick gag for a couple of laughs as the audience leaves the theater.
>
> **"It was never in the cards,"** director Joe Russo tells USA TODAY. **"It was called 'Endgame' for a reason. This is it. This is the ending. The book is closed on that chapter of the Marvel universe and a new book will get written."**
>
> His brother, director Anthony Russo, adds it was a "great thrill" not having to steer the Marvel ship for where it goes next. "This was the first Marvel movie we've done where we weren't thinking about the future."
>
> <sub>[*'Avengers: Endgame': The usual end-credits scene was 'never in the cards' (spoilers)*, Brian Truitt for *USA Today*, May 1st, 2019](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2019/04/30/why-avengers-endgame-doesnt-have-end-credits-scene-spoilers/3630412002/)</sub>

Sure, it's not the end of the MCU and yes, *Far From Home* will happen, but the point was never to leave the door ajar.

Comment: “it was a "great thrill" not having to steer the Marvel ship for where it goes next” — except for, presumably, setting up the Disney Plus shows with Loki, Falcon and the Winter Soldier's scenes.

Comment: Weird that they say "This is the ending. The book is closed on that chapter of the Marvel universe" considering that Far From Home is actually the last movie of phase 3.

Comment: @Parrotmaster: tell that to Tony! Oh wait you can't, he's dead. Tell it to Steve instead! Oh wait you can't, he's taking his afternoon nap cos he's like 94 years old now.

Comment: Note also it was never in the cards, until the re-release that put a whole bunch of stuff (although admittedly not a typical post-credits scene) after the clanks.